# Add new data in app after updating app

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, plist, nsuserdefaults

I’m making simple 3-level app with tableviews on the 1st and 2nd levels.

The names for rows in the tableviews controllers are saved in arrays in plist file. When the user reorders rows I just save the new order as new array in `NSUserdDefaults` object. And each time when I load tableview controller I check if the `NSUserdDefaults` object is empty or not. If it is not empty I take the rows order from the array in `NSUserdDefaults`, otherwise – from plist file.

Here  is sample of code for 1st level tableview controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Topics";

// Checking User changes
NSMutableArray* sectionList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"section"]];

if ([sectionList count] != 0) {
    self.sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sectionList copyItems:YES];}
else {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{

NSString *item = [self.sections objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[self.sections removeObject:item];
[self.sections insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.sections forKey:@"section"];}
```

The problem is about updating. If I add some new data (new rows) in plist file and update app, user will not see new rows in tableview controller, because his `NSUserdDefaults` object is not empty and the rows names and order will be loaded from that object. I was thinking about clearing of `NSUserdDefaults` objects, but I couldn’t find how to do it just after update and no more time.

Have you some ideas how to deal with this?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apporach it this way:

1. Inside NSUserDefaults keep a version number - which will be always bundle version.
2. When loading the app check is that version is lower than current bundle version - do updates on data and update version number to bundle version so it's done only one time.
3. If you've added new properties, just check if they are already on NSUSerDefaults - if not - create them in conversion logic.

Remember than you have to prepare conversion logic that works from any version to any version - if user skipped some version in between your logic will be run only ones on final version.

============================

Extra answers to your questions from comment:

1) what does it mean "bundle version"

NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

This is the version of application - you need to increase it each time you push your app it to Apple Store. You can do it in xcode project settings.

2) how can I check that update happened - i mean, how do i know that i need to increase the version number.

You cannot detect the update process itself and react on it. You have to check that on your application startup. When your app is starting, before you show anything to user, check the "version" from bundle (as answer above) to whatever you have in [NSUserDefaults]. If it's different than you know that application was updated and you have new application version working with old data version. Based on that you can react and update your data + update version to current build version.

3) "new properties" - you mean some extra data that will be saved in NSUserDefaults, but have not been saved before? For instance in version 2 I'll start saving the quantity of rows and the user that hasn't updated to versuion 2, but updates to version 3 will not have that object. So I need to check if all NSUserDefaults objects exist, if not - create them. right?

That's right. In your conversion code, after you detect that version of app is different than version of saved data, you check if variable is there - if not you have to create it and assign default values to it.

Comment: Thank you! I understood the logic,can I ask some extra questions (I'm new in iOS):

Comment: Sure drop me a line or post them in separate question if they are bigger.

Comment: Thanks.
1) what does it mean "bundle version"
2) how can I check that update happened - i mean, how do i know that i need to increase the version number.
3) "new properties" - you mean some extra data that will be saved in NSUserDefaults, but have not been saved before? For instance in version 2 I'll start saving the quantity of rows and the user  that hasn't updated to versuion 2, but updates to version 3 will not have that object. So I need to check if all NSUserDefaults  objects exist, if not - create them. right?